# Gunicorn + Flask - @app.errorhandler(500) being ignored?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I've spent quite a bit of time searching and I'm amazed I've not found an answer to this.

I've got basic @app.errorhandler(500) code in my flask app.  As expected, I get a debugger when running with DEBUG on, and I get my custom error page when it's false.  The next stage of my build though is serving the app from gunicorn in a docker container, and I'm just getting generic "Internal Server Error"s when I do that.  I'm guessing gunicorn is handling the errors now instead of flask?  But I can't for the life of me figure out how to ask it to let flask handle the errors (if that's even possible), or make it use custom error pages.

The final stage will be gunicorn in docker behind nginx, but I think I've found a config directive for nginx to make it let gunicorn handle the errors - I just need to get gunicorn to pass it down one level further so I can use my custom error page, and fire off notifications to relevant people with details regarding the error that occurred (which I suspect I'd lose if I did a custom error page at the gunicorn or nginx level).  Help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Ok, after reading a bunch more, I came back to the conclusion that flask is what should actually be doing the error handling in this situation, so I created a handler for 404, and I do get my custom message - so now I'm just stumped why I don't get my custom message when I trigger a 500, especially considering it *is* working when I fire up the flask development server and turn off debug mode :-/

Comment: Well now even more oddly than that, the same container behind nginx shows my custom 500 error.  I'm really confused now.

Comment: Hi @Hyacin. I am stuck with the same error. The recommendation below from Mhamed doesn't fix it. Did you finally get around this?

Comment: Hey @DominikSajovic, sorry, I don't work at that job or company any more, and haven't touched Flask at all in well over a year and a half, so I have absolutely no memory of this, nor any access to the code anymore to see where we landed with it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the below handle. But I still can't properly explain it. In any case even though the original handling (@app.app_errorhandler(500)) worked fine with the dev flask server and not with gunicorn, I don't believe the problem is to be solved with gunicron. It needs to be solved within the code.

```
@app.app_errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception_error(err):
    """ Defines how to handle Exception errors. """
    logger.error(err)
    return "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR", 500
```

Answer (score 2):

I have Flask + gunicorn + Nginx system, The Internal Server Error was handled by default with Nginx, I added the following config to let 500 errors handled by flask:

```
import logging
from werkzeug.exceptions import InternalServerError
import traceback


@app.errorhandler(InternalServerError)
def handle_500(e):
    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```