# why my flask error handler does not work in gunicorn？

Tags: python, flask, debugging, web, gunicorn

I have a Flask application that uses blueprints to organize different modules. I defined an error handler in errors.py to handle 500 errors to render a customized 500 pages.

```
@main.app_errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    print 'yes'    
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

When I run my application with the Flask built-in server, this error handler works fine, I can  see the `500.html` page. But when I run my application with gunicorn, this error handler does not work, I cannot  see the `500.html` page, I only see a default `Internal Server Error` message.

I have tried the following methods, but none of them worked:
Setting `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS=True` in my application, to let Flask re-raise the exceptions instead of letting gunicorn handle them.
Setting `DEBUG=True` in my application, to let Flask show the error messages instead of letting gunicorn handle them.
Using `app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS']=True`
I am using gunicorn version 20.1.0, and I run gunicorn with this command:

```
gunicorn -w 5 -t 60 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
```

Does anyone know why my error handler does not work in gunicorn? How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Can you try `202` status code for both Flask and Gunicorn? I've faced a similar issue; I was trying to return a `string` with `202` status code but apparently if you return `202`, you can't return anything else. You can also add custom `errorhandler` for `Internal Server Error` like this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/66196310/8658598

Comment: Are you using Python 2? I see a syntax error (missing parentheses on `print`)

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

1. It looks like `print` is missing parentheses, which is going to cause a syntax error
2. You seem to be using an unnecessary variable. Try changing `@main.app_errorhandler(500)` to `@main.app.errorhandler(500)`.

With these changes, a minimal flask app with this error handler looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    raise Exception

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    print('yes')    
    return 'It works!', 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True)
```

The above code shows "It works!" when visiting the index page.